# NUnit can´t find selected assembly

Tags: c#, .net, nunit-2.5

I have a few test-assemblies compiled towards .NET 3.5. When I open nunit-x86.exe however and add any of the assemblies from their build-path I get a

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException...
>
> Server stack trace:     bei
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s)    bei
>   System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)
>   bei NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName,
>   Boolean autoSuites)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName,
>   String testName, Boolean autoSuites)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Within the NUnit Project Editor I point to the test-projects config-file and select .NET-runtime 2.0.xxx as the test-project was compiled Debug/x86 with .NET-Framework 3.5.

I am even unable to load the VS-project related to that assembly which is quite annoying.

This is some piece of my test-projects config-file:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- Register the section handler for the log4net section -->
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <!--  For .NET 2.0 Beta 2 replace the lines with the following -->
      <section name="TestCaseBuilder" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.50215.44, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.50215.44, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

EDIT: also tried with nunit-console, which gave me the following:

> NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350 Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie
>   Poole. Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two,
>   Alexei A. Vorontsov. Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig. All Rights
>   Reserved.
>
> Runtime Environment -    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
>   CLR Version: 2.0.50727.8009 ( Net 3.5 )
>
> ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single Execution Runtime:
>   net-3.5 Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: The file or Assembly "MyTestAssembly.Test, Ver sion=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=39011c0f9e8bb8bc" or one of its dependencies was not found. 
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. FileName: "MyTestAssembly.Test, Version=6.4.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
>   =39011c0f9e8bb8bc"
>
> Server stack trace:    bei
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase,  Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Bo olean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    bei
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidenc e assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    bei System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName,
>   Boolea n autoSuites)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName,
>   String  testName, Boolean autoSuites)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
>   bei NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage
>   (IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean
>   fExecuteInCon text, Object[]& outArgs)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMe
>   ssage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   re qMsg, IMessage retMsg)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgD ata, Int32 type)    bei NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage
>   package)    bei NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)    bei
>   NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)    bei
>   NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Can you try from command prompt using nunit console?

Comment: prints same error. Not quite, get an BadImageException, I update console-output to question